# Confusing about calculating the probe sequence in double hashing

Tags: java, hash, double-hashing

I know that in Double Hashing,

```
h1(key) = key mod 11
h2(key) = 7 - (key mod 7)
```

The `h1` represents starting at location h1(key), `h2` represents the size of the step taken.

But I do not know how to solve for the probe sequence.

For example, if key is `14`.

Can you explain to me why the answer is `3,10,6,2,9,5,1,8,4,0`.

Comment: what does the size of the step mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the size of the table is 11 (positions numbered 0 to 10).  The size of the step is the number to add to the current position to get the next position (modulus the size of the table).

```
h1 = 14 mod 11 = 3
h2 = 7 - (14 mod 7) = 7 - 0 = 7
```

So, the first position, call it `p`, is 3, as given by `h1`. Each subsequent position, `p'` is given by --

```
p' = (p + h2) mod table_size
```

for this example,

```
p' = (p + 7) mod 11
```

so, the second position is --

```
(3 + 7) mod 11 = 10 mod 11 = 10
```

and the third is --

```
(10 + 7) mod 11 = 17 mod 11 = 6
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea now.